# How to get the connection ID/ AuthToken from the Rally java rest API

Tags: java, rest, rally

To find the connection, do we have the cookies in the response or some connection id, authentication token

Answer (score 0):

In the newest [Java REST API for Rally](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava), the [RallyRestApi](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/blob/master/src/com/rallydev/rest/RallyRestApi.java) class grabs a Rally SecurityToken via the protected attachSecurityInfo() method. You can review the source code at the link above starting at line 377 to see how attachSecurityInfo requests the token, but the crux of it is outlined here:

```
protected static final String SECURITY_TOKEN_PARAM_KEY = "key";
private static final String SECURITY_TOKEN_URL = "/security/authorize";
protected static final String SECURITY_TOKEN_KEY = "SecurityToken";

GetResponse getResponse = getWithForceReauth(new GetRequest(SECURITY_TOKEN_URL));
JsonObject operationResult = getResponse.getObject();
JsonPrimitive securityTokenPrimitive = operationResult.getAsJsonPrimitive(SECURITY_TOKEN_KEY);
securityToken = securityTokenPrimitive.getAsString();

public GetResponse getWithForceReauth(GetRequest request) throws IOException {
    return get(request, true);
}
```

Note that this only works for the Java REST package version 1.07 or higher, and requires (and is required by) Rally Webservices API 1.42 or higher.